# input(): "NameError: name 'n' is not defined"

Tags: python, terminal, nameerror

Ok, so I'm writing a grade checking code in python and my code is:

```
unit3Done = str(input("Have you done your Unit 3 Controlled Assessment? (Type y or n): ")).lower()
if unit3Done == "y":
    pass
elif unit3Done == "n":
    print "Sorry. You must have done at least one unit to calculate what you need for an A*"
else:
    print "Sorry. That's not a valid answer."
```

When I run it through my python compiler and I choose `"n"`, I get an error saying:

> "NameError: name 'n' is not defined"

and when I choose `"y"` I get another `NameError` with `'y'` being the problem, but when I do something else, the code runs as normal.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) in Python 2 to get a string, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input)`.

```
>>> type(raw_input())
23
<type 'str'>
>>> type(input())
12
<type 'int'>
```

So, When you enter something like `n` in `input` it thinks that you're looking for a variable named `n`:

```
>>> input()
n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-30-5c7a218085ef>", line 1, in <module>
    type(input())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

`raw_input` works fine:

```
>>> raw_input()
n
'n'
```

---

help on `raw_input`:

```
>>> print raw_input.__doc__
raw_input([prompt]) -> string

Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

help on `input`:

```
>>> print input.__doc__
input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using the [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) on Python 2. Use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead, or switch to Python 3.

`input()` runs `eval()` on the input given, so entering `n` is interpreted as python code, looking for the `n` variable. You could work around that by entering `'n'` (so with quotes) but that is hardly a solution.

In Python 3, `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()`, replacing the version from Python 2 altogether. If your materials (book, course notes, etc.) use `input()` in a manner that expects `n` to work, you probably need to switch to using Python 3 instead.