# Why am i getting Invalid syntax at line 10?

Tags: python

```
 # this program says hello and ask my name.
 print('Hello World')
 print('Whats your name?')
 myname = input()
 print('its good to meet you, ' + myname) #ask for my name
 print('the length of your name is : ')
 print(len(myname))
 print('whats your age?')#ask for my age
 myage = input()
 print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + 1 'in a year')
```

I see syntax error at line 10 of the code i see all the parenthesis are correctly placed.

Comment: Remove the last +1, it's not inside the str function

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want based on the logic of your program

`print('you will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + ' in a year')`

output:

```
Hello World
Whats your name?
Jon Doe
its good to meet you, Jon Doe
the length of your name is : 
7
whats your age?
23
you will be 24 in a year
```

Edit: OP wants me to explain when to use `+` in `print()`. usually if you are printing more than one arguments in your `print()` statement you want to join them using `+`. and when you join arguments together remember their `type` have to be the same. so for example. `print(1 + '2')` would give you an error because `1` is a `int` and  `'2'` is a `str`. you would have to cast the arguments to make them the same. so print(1 + int('2')) would correctly give you `3`

Comment: whats your age?
26
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/punithsrk/Desktop/hello.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage)+1)+1 + 'in a year' )
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + '1 + in a year' )

Comment: this will print me 271 not 27 :(

Comment: that was my old answer. remember to refresh the page and try my edited answer @PunithKothari :)

Comment: thank you so much J.Doe .It helped me .It will be great if you can help me understand where to us the '+' operators as in this case i was not sure how to use it.

Comment: @PunithKothari sure I am so glad to help :) I will type up an explanation. If it worked please accept my answer. check that little green check mark

Comment: @PunirthKothari usually if you are printing more than one argument in your `print()` statement you want to join them using `+`. and when you join arguments together remember their `type` have to be the same.

Comment: Just to note, this will be less confusing @PunithKothari if you used `print('you will be', int(myage) + 1, 'in a year')`which'll put the spaces in for you, make it more clear that you're converting myage to an int and adding one, and avoid the whole concatenating the string together yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You got an extra `1`. change `print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + 1 'in a year')` to

`print('you will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + ' in a year')`

Answer (score 0):

Check your code [here](https://repl.it/KQ2N)

Try :

```
# this program says hello and ask my name.
print('Hello World')
print('Whats your name?')
myname = input()
print('its good to meet you, ' + myname) #ask for my name
print('the length of your name is : ')
print(len(myname))
print('whats your age?')#ask for my age
myage = input()
print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + ' in a year')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will solve your problem:

```
print('Hello World')
print('Whats your name?')
myname = raw_input()
print('its good to meet you, ' + myname) #ask for my name
print('the length of your name is : ')
print(len(myname))
print('whats your age?')#ask for my age
myage = raw_input()
print("you  will be " + str(int(myage) + 1) + " years old by next year")
```

You have missed out the '+' in your line 10 to concatenate your strings. Also there was an unwanted '+ 1' which would have caused another error for you as you were trying to concatenate int and str objects.

Another correction, I have changed the *input()* function with *raw_input()*, as I am using python2. If you need any better explanation on this chnage, you could check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413502/input-nameerror-name-n-is-not-defined).

Answer (score 0):

you should have a string in this command:

```
print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) + 1 'in a year')
```

these are your strings:
*'you will be '*
and
*str(int(myage) + 1)*
and *'in a year'*.
but you are wrong in writing *1 'in a year'*. this is not string.
i think you don't need to the second "1".
you can write:

```
print('you  will be ' + str(int(myage) + 1) +'in a year')
```