# Python EOF Error might be caused by tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, input, user-input

I have some code where I'm trying to get the user input of 4 things. I've never encountered this error before and can't figure out what's wrong. Code:

```py
HOST = input("FTP Host: ")
USER = input("Username: ")
PASS = getpass("Password: ")

tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Output:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    HOST = input("FTP Host: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I've already looked this error up and nothing has helped. I've tried commenting things out and that dossnt do anything. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `input` and tkinter? You should use one or the other.

Comment: I would rather use input but the only way that I could find to show a file selection dialog was with tkinter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input(): "NameError: name 'n' is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17413520/7414759)

Comment: No, im using python 3

Comment: I'll just use tkinter for everything. Thanks